# Can I suppress "authentication required" popup on an asp.net webservice call?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, authentication, web-services

I'm using JQuery to call an asp.net webservice that is set in web.config to only allow logged in users access.

This works fine.  When run locally from Web Developer Express, if I logout and try call the webservice I get a 401 message returned which I then use to redirect the user to the login page. However when run on the live server I'm getting an "authentication required" popup box asking for a username and password.

Why is this? Is there any way I can stop this?

And also, when I do enter the correct username and password, the box just comes up again.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: When you say, "asp.net webservice", do you mean an ASMX Web Service? And, did you know Microsoft now considers ASMX to be "legacy technology"?

Comment: @John - As opposed to? :)  WCF isn't always an option, or a desired one.  I think if you google almost *all* of the [results for citing it as a "legacy technology"](http://www.google.com/search?q=asmx+"legacy+technology"+site:msdn.microsoft.com) are yours ;)  These are still very, *very*, widely used, they're not disappearing anytime in the near future.

Comment: @Nick: try harder. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bkzywba.aspx and every other page in the section. I'm insulted that you would suggest I might be making this up or exaggerating it. That would be unprofessional, which is what you're accusing me of.

Comment: @Nick: furthermore, anyone who is still "widely using" ASMX web services is using technology which is just barely supported. They should be informed that Microsoft is only fixing **business critical** bugs.

Comment: @John - I'm not suggesting that at all, I was suggesting you're inferring a great deal from that one line statement, more than Microsoft means, not making it up :) WebForms is barely supported...really? I strongly disagree with that, I think many others would too. Microsoft will stick a big red deprecated warning at the top of a page when a technology is considered so...but I don't see that yet :)  I know of many very, *very* large customers they have with big systems running on this, it's not going out of the picture any time soon.  Not everyone agrees with the WCF way of doing things...

Comment: Yes, it's an ASMX Web Service. Any ideas?

Comment: @Nick: 1) See https://mvp.support.microsoft.com/profile/John.Saunders. 2) Consider the possibility that I may know some things under NDA that I can't post here.

Comment: @Nick: where did I say anything about webforms? I said **ASMX web services** are barely supported, at least in the sense of bugs getting fixed. Anyone who doesn't care if bugs get fixed is welcome to use them.

Comment: @John - Perhaps you can you clarify this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bkzywba.aspx is for "XML Web services", "ASMX" doesn't appear on that page, or in that section (WCF, among other things can also return XML, so how do you connect it specifically to ASMX? the naming on this confuses me a bit). I can't find any documentation in MSDN connecting ASMX to legacy (I use them for JSON, not XML). Don't take this the wrong way...but everything I search for, only your name connects the two, I'm simply asking for the MSDN documentation for it, for when you say "Microsoft considers..."

Comment: @Nick: the page, and hence the section, is entitled "XML Web Services Created Using ASP.NET and XML Web Service Clients". That's ASMX web services. "ASMX" (pronounced "assemX") is what Microsoft calls them internally. As to "legacy", it says, "This topic is specific to a legacy technology. XML Web services and XML Web service clients should now be created using Windows Communication Foundation". What question does that leave unanswered?

Comment: @John - The question was because of this bit: "...what Microsoft calls them internally"...leaving that connection very unclear from the exposed documentation :)

Comment: @Nick: the link I gave you is entirely about "ASMX" web services. There's nothing about WCF in there. I don't understand how there could be any misunderstanding about which technology is "a legacy technology", regardless of who calls it what!

Comment: @John - I think the problem is perspective here...in 10 years I've *never* heard "ASMX" referred to as "XML Web Services", in fact, I've only used them to return XML twice.  Without knowing that's what Microsoft calls them, that documentation and note have no relation to "ASMX". For example: if I said "Fibblejigs are deprecated"...now let's say my company calls WinForms "Fibblejigs"...how are you supposed to connect those two, not being in my company and knowing our internal names?  See my point :) They should use the externally used term to describe things in documentation, not internal ones.

Comment: @Nick: I'm still not understanding. Ignore names. Read a couple of those sections. See what part of the .NET Framework they're about. Whatever you or Microsoft or anyone else want to call that area of the Framework, the same notice is at the top of all of those pages. Whatever it's called, it's "a legacy technology".

Comment: @Nick: I've had a blog post on this for almost a year ([Microsoft says: ASMX Web Services are a “Legacy Technology”](http://johnwsaundersiii.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!600A2BE4A82EA0A6!860.entry) ). Be the first to comment on it. This isn't the place.

Comment: @Nick: [Microsoft says: ASMX Web Services are a “Legacy Technology”](http://johnwsaundersiii.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!600A2BE4A82EA0A6!860.entry)

Answer (score 0):

In production you would just need to disable IIS authentication for the specific pages in the IIS manager